# d3 force graph with divs and d3 zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hello Stackoverflowcommunity!
I am having trouble getting d3 zoom working in my d3force-directed graph. I could achieve that it is zooming and panning but doing so breaks the alignment between the nodes and the links and i don't know how i could fix it.... I created a fiddle showing what i mean. https://jsfiddle.net/5jgrf5h8/5/

This is the code where i perform the zoom:

```
svg.call(d3.zoom()
  //.scaleExtent([1 / 2, 4])
  .on("zoom", zoomed))
.on("dblclick.zoom", null);
//.on("wheel.zoom", null);

function zoomed() {
  //link.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
  link.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.transform.x + "," + d3.event.transform.y + ") scale(" + d3.event.transform.k + ")");
  node.style("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.transform.x + "px," + d3.event.transform.y + "px) scale(" + d3.event.transform.k + ")");

  simulation.alphaTarget(0.001).restart();
  simulation.alphaTarget(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you apply the CSS `scale` on your `div` nodes, it's with an origin of `0,0` not with an origin of the position they are current in.

Try this:

```
function zoomed() {

    // apply CSS scale with respect to current position
    node.each(function(d){
    var self = d3.select(this),
            x = self.style("left"),
        y = self.style("top");
    self.style("transform-origin", "-" + x + " -" + y);
  })

  link.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.transform.x + "," + d3.event.transform.y + ") scale(" + d3.event.transform.k + ")");
  node.style("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.transform.x + "px," + d3.event.transform.y + "px) scale(" + d3.event.transform.k + ")");

  simulation.alphaTarget(0.001).restart();
  simulation.alphaTarget(0);
}
```

---

Updated [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5jgrf5h8/6/)

Comment: Hi Mark! Thanks for your help! I can see that it improved but it's still not perfect for example when you zoom out it will still break the alignment and especially when u drag the nodes while zoomed out they still behave strange. Do you have an idea how to improve this?

Comment: I got it now. instead transforming all the nodes and link i transformed their parent elements and for the divs i set transform origin to 0px. I updated my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5jgrf5h8/7/