# Apply zoom to tooltip in D3 tree

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, tree

I'm trying to create a HTML tooltip that can be zoomed in and out with D3 zoom effect. I've managed to have it working partially, because the positioning of the tooltip is wrong, but it is being zoomed correctly.

I've tried something similar to what has been said in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733581/d3-force-graph-with-divs-and-d3-zoom), but without success.

What do I need to do? I guess it's only a problem with the zoom event of the `zoomBehaviours` object, but I can't find the way to solve it.

In the following snippet you can see what's the current state of the tooltip.

```js
var data = {
    "name": "Eve",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Cain",
            "info": "Cain"
        },
        {
            "name": "Seth",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Enos",
                    "info": "Seth"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Noam",
                    "info": "Noam"
                }
            ],
            "info": "Seth"
        },
        {
            "name": "Abel",
            "info": "Abel"
        },
        {
            "name": "Awan",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Enoch",
                    "info": "Enoch"
                }
            ],
            "info": "Awan"
        },
        {
            "name": "Azura",
            "info": "Azura"
        }
    ],
    "info": "Eve"
};

const DX = 80;
const DY = 80;

const RECT_WIDTH = 40;
const RECT_HEIGHT = 15;

const TRANSITION_DURATION = 700;
const TOOLTIP_TRANSTION_DURATION = 300;

// Zoom constants
const MIN_ZOOM = 0.15;
const MAX_ZOOM = Infinity;

// Get size available
let width = $(document).width();
let height = $(document).height();

// New tree layout with default settings
let tree = d3.tree().nodeSize([DX, DY]);

let diagonal = d3.linkVertical()
    .x(d => d.x + RECT_WIDTH / 2)
    .y(d => d.y + RECT_HEIGHT / 2);

/* 
    Function that creates the first tree with the default layout
*/
function createRoot() {
    let root = d3.hierarchy(data);
    root.x0 = DX / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;
    root.descendants().forEach((d, i) => {
        d.id = i;
        d._children = d.children;
        if (d.depth >= 0) d.children = null;
    });
    return root;
}

/* 
    Function that updates all the nodes in a tree according to the click event
*/
function update(source) {
    const nodes = root.descendants().reverse();
    const links = root.links();

    // Compute the new tree layout
    tree(root);

    const transition = svg.transition()
        .duration(TRANSITION_DURATION)
        .tween("resize", window.ResizeObserver ? null : () => () => svg.dispatch("toggle"));

    /*=============================NODE SECTION============================== */
    // Obtain all the nodes
    const node = gNode.selectAll("g")
        .data(nodes, d => d.id);

        // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    const nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", d => `translate(${source.x0},${source.y0})`)
        .on("click", function (event, d) {
            if (d.children) // Node expanded -> Collapse
                collapse(d);
            else // Node collapsed -> Expand
                d.children = d._children
            update(d);
            centerNode(d);
        })
        .on("mouseover", d => div.transition()
                                .duration(TOOLTIP_TRANSTION_DURATION)
                                .style("opacity", 1))
        .on("mousemove", (event, d) =>
            div.style("left", event.pageX + "px").style("top", event.pageY + "px")
                .html(
                "<table style='font-size: 10px; font-family: sans-serif;' >"+
                "<tr><td>Name: </td><td>"+d.data.info+"</td></tr>"+
                "</table>")
            )
        .on("mouseout", d => div.transition()
                                .duration(TOOLTIP_TRANSTION_DURATION)
                                .style("opacity", 0))

    nodeEnter.append("rect")
        .attr("class", d => d._children && !d.children ? "notExpanded" : "expanded")
        .attr("height", RECT_HEIGHT)
        .attr("width", RECT_WIDTH)
        
    // Inside node text
    nodeEnter.append("text")
        // The position of the text is centered 
        .attr("x", RECT_WIDTH / 2)
        .attr("y", RECT_HEIGHT / 2)
        .text(d => d.data.name)
        .clone(true).lower();

    // Transition nodes to their new position (update)
    var nodeUpdate = node.merge(nodeEnter).transition(transition)
        .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`)
        // Show the nodes
        .attr("fill-opacity", 1)
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 1);
    
    // Update class of rectangles
    nodeUpdate.select('rect')
        .attr("class", d => d._children && !d.children ? "notExpanded" : "expanded");

    //  Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position
    node.exit().transition(transition).remove()
        .attr("transform", d => `translate(${source.x},${source.y})`)
        // Hide the nodes
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 0);

    /*=============================LINK SECTION============================== */
    const link = gLink.selectAll("path")
        .data(links, d => d.target.id);

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position
    const linkEnter = link.enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("x", RECT_WIDTH / 2)
        .attr("y", RECT_HEIGHT / 2)
        .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)") // add the arrow to the link end
        
        .attr("d", d => {
            const o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
        });

    // Transition links to their new position
    link.merge(linkEnter).transition(transition)
        // In this case the link will be changed in order to have the arrows in
        // the correct position 
        .attr("d", d => diagonal({
            source: d.source,
            target: {
                x: d.target.x,
                y: d.target.y - RECT_HEIGHT
            }
        }));

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position
    link.exit().transition(transition).remove()
        .attr("d", d => {
            const o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
        });

    // Stash the old positions for transition
    root.eachBefore(d => {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });
}

/*
    Function that centers a given node in the screen. 
*/
function centerNode(source) {
    let scale = d3.zoomTransform(d3.select("svg").node()).k;
    let x = -source.x0 * scale + width / 2 - RECT_WIDTH / 2 * scale;
    let y = -source.y0 * scale + height / 2 - RECT_HEIGHT / 2 * scale;
    // Define the transition
    const transition = svg.transition()
        .duration(TRANSITION_DURATION)
        .tween("resize", window.ResizeObserver ? null : () => () => svg.dispatch("toggle"));
    // Move all the nodes based on the previous parameters
    svg.transition(transition)
        .call(zoomBehaviours.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(x,y).scale(scale));
}

/*
    Function that collapses all the subtree of a given node.
*/
function collapse(node) {
    if (node.children) { // Expanded
        node.children = null;
        node._children.forEach(collapse)
    }
}

/*
    Function that creates the possibility to add arrows to links
*/
function createArrows() {
    defs.selectAll("marker")
    .data(["end"])      // Different link/path types can be defined here
    .enter().append("marker")    // This section adds in the arrows
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", `0 -5 10 10`)
    .attr("refX", 0)
    .attr("refY", 0)
    .attr("markerWidth", 5)
    .attr("markerHeight", 5)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
}

// Root creation
const root = createRoot();

// SVG variable that will contain all the configuration for the images.
// We need to append it to the body
const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");

const div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

// SVG group that will contain two groups declared below
const g = svg.append("g");
    
// Two groups: One of links and another of nodes
const gLink = g.append("g");
const gNode = g.append("g");

// Zoom configuration
const zoomBehaviours = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([MIN_ZOOM, MAX_ZOOM])
    .on('zoom', (event) => {
        g.attr('transform', event.transform);
        div.style("transform", "translate(" + event.transform.x + "px," + event.transform.y + "px) scale(" + event.transform.k + ")");
        div.style("transform-origin", "0px 0px");
    });

// Add the zoom so that svg knows that it is available
svg.call(zoomBehaviours);

// build the arrow.
let defs = svg.append("svg:defs");
createArrows();

update(root);
centerNode(root);
```

```css
.node {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.node .notExpanded {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1.2;
    fill: lightskyblue;
}
.node .expanded {
    fill: lightskyblue;
}
.node text {
    fill: black;
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    text-anchor: middle;
    text-align: center;
    dominant-baseline: central;
}
.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1.5;
    stroke-opacity: 0.5;
}
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: rgb(86, 145, 221);
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        
    </body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./src/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made it with a simple modification of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733581/d3-force-graph-with-divs-and-d3-zoom). The problem was that I was shifting the tooltip with a translate event that was not necessary. This would be the look of the code after the change. Notice that I only changed the `zoom` event of the `zoomBehaviours` object.

```js
var data = {
    "name": "Eve",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Cain",
            "info": "Cain"
        },
        {
            "name": "Seth",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Enos",
                    "info": "Seth"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Noam",
                    "info": "Noam"
                }
            ],
            "info": "Seth"
        },
        {
            "name": "Abel",
            "info": "Abel"
        },
        {
            "name": "Awan",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Enoch",
                    "info": "Enoch"
                }
            ],
            "info": "Awan"
        },
        {
            "name": "Azura",
            "info": "Azura"
        }
    ],
    "info": "Eve"
};

const DX = 80;
const DY = 80;

const RECT_WIDTH = 40;
const RECT_HEIGHT = 15;

const TRANSITION_DURATION = 700;
const TOOLTIP_TRANSTION_DURATION = 300;

// Zoom constants
const MIN_ZOOM = 0.15;
const MAX_ZOOM = Infinity;

// Get size available
let width = $(document).width();
let height = $(document).height();

// New tree layout with default settings
let tree = d3.tree().nodeSize([DX, DY]);

let diagonal = d3.linkVertical()
    .x(d => d.x + RECT_WIDTH / 2)
    .y(d => d.y + RECT_HEIGHT / 2);

/* 
    Function that creates the first tree with the default layout
*/
function createRoot() {
    let root = d3.hierarchy(data);
    root.x0 = DX / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;
    root.descendants().forEach((d, i) => {
        d.id = i;
        d._children = d.children;
        if (d.depth >= 0) d.children = null;
    });
    return root;
}

/* 
    Function that updates all the nodes in a tree according to the click event
*/
function update(source) {
    const nodes = root.descendants().reverse();
    const links = root.links();

    // Compute the new tree layout
    tree(root);

    const transition = svg.transition()
        .duration(TRANSITION_DURATION)
        .tween("resize", window.ResizeObserver ? null : () => () => svg.dispatch("toggle"));

    /*=============================NODE SECTION============================== */
    // Obtain all the nodes
    const node = gNode.selectAll("g")
        .data(nodes, d => d.id);

        // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    const nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", d => `translate(${source.x0},${source.y0})`)
        .on("click", function (event, d) {
            if (d.children) // Node expanded -> Collapse
                collapse(d);
            else // Node collapsed -> Expand
                d.children = d._children
            update(d);
            centerNode(d);
        })
        .on("mouseover", d => div.transition()
                                .duration(TOOLTIP_TRANSTION_DURATION)
                                .style("opacity", 1))
        .on("mousemove", (event, d) =>
            div.style("left", event.pageX + "px").style("top", event.pageY + "px")
                .html(
                "<table style='font-size: 10px; font-family: sans-serif;' >"+
                "<tr><td>Name: </td><td>"+d.data.info+"</td></tr>"+
                "</table>")
            )
        .on("mouseout", d => div.transition()
                                .duration(TOOLTIP_TRANSTION_DURATION)
                                .style("opacity", 0))

    nodeEnter.append("rect")
        .attr("class", d => d._children && !d.children ? "notExpanded" : "expanded")
        .attr("height", RECT_HEIGHT)
        .attr("width", RECT_WIDTH)
        
    // Inside node text
    nodeEnter.append("text")
        // The position of the text is centered 
        .attr("x", RECT_WIDTH / 2)
        .attr("y", RECT_HEIGHT / 2)
        .text(d => d.data.name)
        .clone(true).lower();

    // Transition nodes to their new position (update)
    var nodeUpdate = node.merge(nodeEnter).transition(transition)
        .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`)
        // Show the nodes
        .attr("fill-opacity", 1)
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 1);
    
    // Update class of rectangles
    nodeUpdate.select('rect')
        .attr("class", d => d._children && !d.children ? "notExpanded" : "expanded");

    //  Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position
    node.exit().transition(transition).remove()
        .attr("transform", d => `translate(${source.x},${source.y})`)
        // Hide the nodes
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 0);

    /*=============================LINK SECTION============================== */
    const link = gLink.selectAll("path")
        .data(links, d => d.target.id);

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position
    const linkEnter = link.enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("x", RECT_WIDTH / 2)
        .attr("y", RECT_HEIGHT / 2)
        .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)") // add the arrow to the link end
        
        .attr("d", d => {
            const o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
        });

    // Transition links to their new position
    link.merge(linkEnter).transition(transition)
        // In this case the link will be changed in order to have the arrows in
        // the correct position 
        .attr("d", d => diagonal({
            source: d.source,
            target: {
                x: d.target.x,
                y: d.target.y - RECT_HEIGHT
            }
        }));

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position
    link.exit().transition(transition).remove()
        .attr("d", d => {
            const o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
        });

    // Stash the old positions for transition
    root.eachBefore(d => {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });
}

/*
    Function that centers a given node in the screen. 
*/
function centerNode(source) {
    let scale = d3.zoomTransform(d3.select("svg").node()).k;
    let x = -source.x0 * scale + width / 2 - RECT_WIDTH / 2 * scale;
    let y = -source.y0 * scale + height / 2 - RECT_HEIGHT / 2 * scale;
    // Define the transition
    const transition = svg.transition()
        .duration(TRANSITION_DURATION)
        .tween("resize", window.ResizeObserver ? null : () => () => svg.dispatch("toggle"));
    // Move all the nodes based on the previous parameters
    svg.transition(transition)
        .call(zoomBehaviours.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(x,y).scale(scale));
}

/*
    Function that collapses all the subtree of a given node.
*/
function collapse(node) {
    if (node.children) { // Expanded
        node.children = null;
        node._children.forEach(collapse)
    }
}

/*
    Function that creates the possibility to add arrows to links
*/
function createArrows() {
    defs.selectAll("marker")
    .data(["end"])      // Different link/path types can be defined here
    .enter().append("marker")    // This section adds in the arrows
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", `0 -5 10 10`)
    .attr("refX", 0)
    .attr("refY", 0)
    .attr("markerWidth", 5)
    .attr("markerHeight", 5)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
}

// Root creation
const root = createRoot();

// SVG variable that will contain all the configuration for the images.
// We need to append it to the body
const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");

const div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

// SVG group that will contain two groups declared below
const g = svg.append("g");
    
// Two groups: One of links and another of nodes
const gLink = g.append("g");
const gNode = g.append("g");

// Zoom configuration
const zoomBehaviours = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([MIN_ZOOM, MAX_ZOOM])
    .on('zoom', (event) => {
        g.attr('transform', event.transform);
        div.style("transform", "scale(" + event.transform.k + ")");
        // Change the reference of the tooltip so that the top left vertex is 
        // where the pointer lies
        div.style("transform-origin", "0px 0px");
    });

// Add the zoom so that svg knows that it is available
svg.call(zoomBehaviours);

// build the arrow.
let defs = svg.append("svg:defs");
createArrows();

update(root);
centerNode(root);
```

```css
.node {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.node .notExpanded {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1.2;
    fill: lightskyblue;
}
.node .expanded {
    fill: lightskyblue;
}
.node text {
    fill: black;
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    text-anchor: middle;
    text-align: center;
    dominant-baseline: central;
}
.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1.5;
    stroke-opacity: 0.5;
}
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: rgb(86, 145, 221);
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        
    </body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./src/main.js"></script>
</html>
```